# How to set as a default value in a Symfony 2 form field the authentified username from the FOSUserBundle

Tags: forms, symfony, fosuserbundle

i find this snippet useful indeed to put a default value in my form while creating it

```
 $builder
 ->add('myfield', 'text', array(
     'label' => 'Field',
     'data' => 'Default value'))
 ;
```

what if i want to replace 'default value' with an authentified person from the FOSUser bundle? ( that return true to is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED"))

i can retrieve that name on a twig file with

```
 {{ app.user.username }}
```

i have also done it in a controller method with

```
    $username=$this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getUsername()
```

but i can't manage to make this working in my form!

i am not sure i understand that container thing well ...neither how to transfer variables betweenn classes and controller...
 something around this maybe??

```
      ->add('myfield', 'text', array(
     'label' => 'Field',
     'data' => FOS\UserBundle\Model::$this->getUsername()))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can passe variable from your controller to your form :

in your controller :

```
$username=$this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getUsername()
$form = $this->createForm(new MyFormType($username), $entity);
```

in your form :

```
protected $username;

public function __construct (array $username = null)
{
        $this->username = $username ;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
   $builder  
     ->add('myfield', 'text', array(
      'label' => 'Field',
      'data' => $this->username))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to set default values into a form is to set them on the underlying data object for the form, as in this example from the Symfony documentation on building a form:

```
public function newAction()
{
    // create a task and give it some dummy data for this example
    $task = new Task();
    $task->setTask('Write a blog post');
    $task->setDueDate(new \DateTime('tomorrow'));

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
        ->add('task', 'text')
        ->add('dueDate', 'date')
        ->getForm();

    return $this->render('AcmeTaskBundle:Default:new.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

In this example, the form's underlying data object is a Task and the values set on the task are the default values to be displayed in the form. The task object is not persistent. This approach works just as well with a form class and assuming the underlying object for your form is a User would look something like this:

> ```
> $username = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getUsername();
>
> $user = new User();
> $user->setUsername($username);
> // could set any other default values on user here
>
> $form = $this->createForm(new MyFormClass(), $user);
> ```

The disadvantage of this approach is if the form is used in many places requiring the same defaults the code would be repeated. This is not a situation I've come across so far - my User forms are re-used for create/edit but edit doesn't require the defaults.